# Host aspnet core application with ports defined in UseKestrel

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server, kestrel

I want to host my application in windows server. I wanna use Mqtt over tcp and WebSosckets.

If i publish in IIS using WebDeploy, I cannot reach ports (1883 and 5000) specified in Program.cs

```
       `private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(o => {
                o.ListenAnyIP(1883, l => l.UseMqtt());
                o.ListenAnyIP(5000); // default http pipeline
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()    
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();`
```

but if I  use `dotnet run` (in server) everything is okej and i can access mqqt on port 1883

Is there a way to publish application in IIS and still have access to those ports?
What im missing ?

Answer (score 0):

For hosting in IIS, `UseKestrel` is used to configure Kestrel Server, and IIS is used for reverse proxy. The requests from client first go into IIS, and then route to Kestrel.

So, if you want to be able to access web app from `1883`, you need to configure the web site in iis with port `1883`.

You could create a new site with `1883` from IIS, and then publish your project to this site from VS Web Deploy.

[image]

Comment: I like to access application in port 5000, but i need port 1883 to handle MQTT connection. 
neither of ports doesnt work with webdeploy :S